# How to list all the products based on the color variants

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How to list all the products based on the color variants.

like i have **3 colors** for attribute 'color'
    i.e., Red , Green, Blue and

**3 Sizes** 

i.e. Small, Medium, Large.

Now i have created 9 different simple products with visibility "Not visible individually" and made an association with Configurable product. Normally magento will display only one configurable product with all the options. but what i want is to list the products based on the color like i have to display three products viz, red product with it's size options, green product with it's size options...like that.

How to can i do that. any Help would be appreciated...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it by creating options for simple products and no need to create Configurable product then create custom module to retrieve products ids by options but this will be a long time process. an easy way is to create two categories for colors and size and create the child categories of them then you can retrieve your products under any specific category using Magento EAV Design Pattern

Comment: i am little bit confusing with your answer. and one more thing that should have to be work with Color swatches also. like for color based configurable product images and prices and swatches have to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

How about creating 3 configurable products, one each for each colour?

Comment: no. it should be only one Configurable Product in Admin side

Comment: But you said you want to display three products by colour. Why do you want only one configurable product?

Comment: it is a client requirement. actually if we display only one Configurable product then catalog looks like less number of products as he has all configurable products there is no simple products to show. that's why he needs the products based on the color variants.

Comment: The client requirement is to show 3 sets of products by colour, how you do that is surely a configuration issue? So using 3 configurable products should be ok surely? As an alternative, how about using colour categories (say a red, green and blue), associate the simple products to the one for them and the configurable product to all?Might that work?